# How to calculate the deduction fee for subscribing to a more expensive plan again with RecurringApplication Charge from Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

Upgrading an appAnchor link to section titled "Upgrading an app"
When a merchant upgrades to a more expensive subscription, Shopify prorates the amount of the charge with the same billing cycle. For example, if a merchant begins a 30-day billing cycle on a $5.00 plan, and then upgrades to a $15.00 plan on day 15 of the billing cycle, then the merchant is charged $5.00 + ($15.00 - $5.00) * (15/30) = $10.00 USD.

I create a more More expensive subscriptions 39.9$, previous is 19.9$, buy why i should pay 39.9$, in document says It shouldn't be $19.9 + ($39.90 - $19.90) * (n/30) = x USD

here is my code

```
        import { shopifyApp } from "@shopify/shopify-app-express";
        const shopify = shopifyApp({...})
        const application_charge = new shopify.api.rest.RecurringApplicationCharge({
            session: res.locals.shopify.session,
        })
        application_charge.name = name
        application_charge.price = subscriptionType === 'pro' ? 39.9 : 19.9;
        application_charge.return_url = returnUrl
        application_charge.test = true;
        await application_charge.save({
            update: true,
        });
```

[image]